# Synchronisation of entity already hydrated after update via QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a simple question after an update with a query builder what append to the entity already loaded, it seems that they are "desynchronize".

The following code show the probleme

```
/** @var  EntityManager $em */
$repository = new PersonneRepository();
/** @var Personne $persone */
$persone = $repository->find('42');

echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";

$invertedSexe = $persone->getSexe() == 'F' ? 'M' : 'F';
echo 'New Sexe : '.$invertedSexe."\n";
$q = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$q->update($repository->getClassName(), 'p')
 ->set('p.sexe', ":sexe")
 ->where('p.id = :id')
 ->setParameters(array(
     'sexe' => $invertedSexe,
     'id' => $persone->getId()
 ));
$q->getQuery()->execute();
echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";
$persone = $repository->find('42');
echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";
```

Output :

```
SEXE : M
New Sexe : F
SEXE : M
SEXE : M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't update your $persone object while just updating your Database.

So either you go

1. the ORM way which means you `$persone->setSexe()` and then flush it

this could look like e.g.:

```
/** @var  EntityManager $em */
$repository = new PersonneRepository();
/** @var Personne $persone */
$persone = $repository->find('42');

echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";

$invertedSexe = $persone->getSexe() == 'F' ? 'M' : 'F';
echo 'New Sexe : '.$invertedSexe."\n";

$persone->setSexe($invertedSexe);
$em->persist($persone);
$em->flush();

echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";
$persone = $repository->find('42');
echo 'SEXE : ' . $persone->getSexe() . "\n";
```

2. the DBAL way which means you update it your DB first and then either refresh your $person again (`find`ing it still gets you the object not the updated db entity) again or set your $persone->sexe manually.

The refresh mentioned in option 2 is done in your code as:

```
 $em->refresh($persone); // instead of your last $respository->find('42');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation :

> DQL UPDATE statements are ported directly into a Database UPDATE
>   statement and therefore bypass any locking scheme, events and do not
>   increment the version column. Entities that are already loaded into
>   the persistence context will NOT be synced with the updated database
>   state. It is recommended to call EntityManager#clear() and retrieve
>   new instances of any affected entity.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries